# How to position div over an 100% width image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

I've tride lots of ways to do that. But I still can't.
I want to put div with my logo or just image over my 100% width image. Of course when width of window, and of image change than height between these blue areas will change to. And i want my logo to be always on middle of that height.

Comment: uh...please post an image of what you are trying to achieve and any code you have tried so far. We have nothing to work with here.

Comment: You should add some code that you have tried, that did not work, so we can go from there.

Comment: Share some code so people could better understand you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are using jQuery.

You should use absolute positioning for your logo div or img, and calculate it's new position based on boundaries of the 100% image. So something like this should serve your purpose.

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
   var container = $( "#your100percentimage" );
   var logo = $("#yourlogo");

   var containerWidth = container.width();
   var containerHeight = container.height();

   var logoHeight = logo.height();
   var logoY = container.offset().top + (containerHeight - logoHeight) / 2;

   logo.css("top", logoY+"px");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap img with div

div - position relative

img - position absolute top 0 left 0 bottom 0 right 0

logo - position absolute top 50% left ???

```
<div><img/><logo/></div>
```